# How to configure checkstyle rule in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, checkstyle

I have configured Check-style plugin in Jenkins.
I wanted to know how can i provide custom check-style rule File(Rule.xml) to Jenkins.

Can any one help on this

Answer (score 0):

You can define the ruleset at running it. You can copy the xml file you already have and adjust it as you like.

```
java -jar checkstyle-8.8-all.jar -c /google_checks.xml MyClass.java
```